# Horizontal stacked bar chart in python giving multiple charts in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to make a stacked horizontal bar chart with a specified size, title, and legend location in Jupyter Notebooks. When I use other Stack Overflow solutions I get several graphs printed out instead of just one. Here's a simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [3,5,4,2,1]
b = [3,4,5,2,1]
c = [3,5,4,6,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : a,'b' : b, 'c' : c})
df.plot.barh(stacked=True);

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(6,6)

ax.set_title("My ax title")
#plt.title("My plt title") # This seems to be identical to ax.set_title
# Which is prefered?
ax.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

This code gives me the following two plots. The plot is what I'm looking for but my size and legend location are ignored and the title was put on a second graph that I don't want.

[image][image]

Note: I'm using plot.barh from pandas because I got it to work but I would be just as happy to do it directly from matplotlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the return object from the `plot` to the variable `ax`.  Then do what you wanted.

```
a = [3,5,4,2,1]
b = [3,4,5,2,1]
c = [3,5,4,6,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : a,'b' : b, 'c' : c})
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True);

ax.figure.set_size_inches(6,6)

ax.set_title("My ax title")
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
```

[image]

---

Or alternatively, you could have referenced your created `ax` in the `plot` call.

```
a = [3,5,4,2,1]
b = [3,4,5,2,1]
c = [3,5,4,6,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : a,'b' : b, 'c' : c})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(6,6)

df.plot.barh(stacked=True, ax=ax);

ax.set_title("My ax title")
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the plot using

```
df.plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

Then again you are creating an empty plot using

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Get rid of that and that will take care of the second empty plot

You can pass the parameters inside plot like

```
df.plot.barh(stacked=True,title = "My ax title", figsize = (6,6))
```

Comment: This is perfectly accurate.